# Почему частицы не летят в направлении ядра

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

*в коде все работает, но при этом частицы появляются и летают в куче в левой стороне зависимо от количества итераций*

```
import pygame
import numpy as np


pygame.init()


width, height = 1300, 850
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Опыт Резерфорда")


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)


gold_nucleus = np.array([width // 2, height // 2])
num_particles = 1000
num_iterations = 1100


def simulate_rutherford_experiment(num_particles, num_iterations):
    # Задаем начальные параметры
    alpha_particles = np.zeros((num_particles, 2))
    alpha_speed = 1

    
    for _ in range(num_iterations):
        # Генерируем случайное направление для каждой частицы
        directions = np.random.uniform(0, 1 * np.pi, num_particles)

        # Обновляем положение частиц
        alpha_particles[:, 0] += alpha_speed * np.cos(directions)
        alpha_particles[:, 1] += alpha_speed * np.sin(directions)

        # Проверяем столкновение с ядром золота
        distances = np.linalg.norm(alpha_particles - gold_nucleus, axis=1)
        collided_indices = np.where(distances < 5)

        # Отражаем столкнувшиеся частицы
        alpha_particles[collided_indices] -= alpha_particles[collided_indices] - gold_nucleus

    # Возвращаем положения частиц после симуляции
    return alpha_particles

# Параметры симуляции


# Выполняем симуляцию
positions = simulate_rutherford_experiment(num_particles, num_iterations)

# Основной цикл игры
running = True
while running:
    # Очистка экрана
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Обновление положения частиц
    positions = simulate_rutherford_experiment(num_particles, num_iterations)

    # Отрисовка частиц
    for position in positions:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (int(position[0]), int(position[1])), 2)
    # Convert gold_nucleus to a tuple of floats

    # Отрисовка ядра золота
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, gold_nucleus, 10)

    # Обновление экрана
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Обработка событий
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
# Завершение работы pygame
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Если вы распечатаете `int(position[0]), int(position[1]`, то увидите, что частицы рисуются там, где вы их задаете.

Comment: Почитайте про Sprite и Group, хотя бы здесь https://younglinux.info/pygame/sprite.